# jQuery - sometimes button clicks are not handled (trapped) on event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my jQuery based code I use a button click event handler.
The problem described on title here occurs sometimes - approximately after 20 successfull clicks on the button. When it occurs, then I have to move mouse pointer out of the button area and move it again back over the button in order click event to be handled.
What could cause this strange behaviour?

Here is the event handler:

```
function advice() {
    rebuildCacheBtnElem.bind("click", function (event) {
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
       event.preventDefault();

       switch (configBtnAction) {
          case CONFIG_ACTION_REBUILD:
               rebuildCacheBtnElem.text("Cancel");
               configState = CONFIG_STATE_BUSY;
               goNextConfigStep(configPages, configBtnAction, CONFIG_ACTION_FINISH);
               worker(0, 0);
               break;

          case CONFIG_ACTION_FINISH:
               if (configState == CONFIG_STATE_FINISHED_SUCCESS) {
                  treeId.populateTree();
               }
               else if (configState == CONFIG_STATE_BUSY) {
                  sendCommand({ cancel: cancelGUID }, function (data) {
                     resetGUI();
                  });
               }
               else {
                  resetGUI();
               }
               break;
       }

       window.console.log(configBtnAction);
    });
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ demo please.

Comment: Here is the simplified version of my logic - http://jsfiddle.net/9Gad5/1/ . Unfortunately the problem does not appears in the jsfiddle example. Please give me any directions. I will follow any suggestions here. I suspected duplicated id's problem, but still not sure.

Comment: How should we be able to solve the problem if the demo does not even expose the problem? But you made an important step: You reduced the code so far that the problem disappears. Hence the problem must b with the code you removed. Add that code back step by step and see when the problem occurs again. Then you find out what causes the problem.

Comment: Ok. Finally I've composed a jsfiddle example - http://jsfiddle.net/RVhyW/ to expose the mentioned problem. In order to successfully reproduce the problem you must repeatedly click on the button
 and observe whether the printed text is changing. It is important to move mouse pointer out of the button area after every click.  Tested on latest Chrome Browser. After about 20-30 clicks the problem occurs.

Comment: Last update: http://jsfiddle.net/RVhyW/2/